# Escaping strings when passing to wire:click event

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

I have a `wire:click` defined as `wire:click="sendString('{{ $search }}', 'example')"` where `example` is a fixed parameter and `$search` is dynamic based on a `wire:model` somewhere else on the page.

The problem is if the user uses single or double quotes. For instance if they input *didn’t* then I’ll get `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 't'. Expected ')' to end an argument list`.

I’m not sure if/how I can use javascript’s `unescape()` in this case?

Comment: One dirty way of doing it could be simply `sendString('{{ str_replace("'", "\'", $search) }}', 'example')` -- since you probably can't fix it client-side. Is it on the same component, or does that click fire a method on a separate component?

Comment: Ah yes could do that indeed. But then I'd also need something for double quotes right? I think that `str_replace` accepts an array? It's on the same component.

Comment: Well, since its on the same component, you already have `$this->search` available within `sendString()`, don't you?

Comment: Yes I do, I'm not sure I get the difference between accessing `$this->search` and `$search` (as a public property on the component); the quote problems stays the same?

Comment: My point is that you don't have to pass it to `sendString()` at all since its already a property of that component. So instead of accepting the string as an argument, you use the property. They should be the same.

Comment: Ah right, got it. The problem is is that the property is already used in the component, and this `wire:click` is a specific separate interaction on a click that also uses the property, so I need to fire an event for that.

Comment: I still fail to see the problem - instead of accepting `$search` into `sendString()`, remove the argument and use `$this->search` directly inside the method instead.

Comment: The scenario is: someone clicks on a button that has a _predefined_ value, like 'test string'. That value then needs to be set as the value for `$search` when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Can't you predefine it in the component? If that `$search` variable is equal to the predefined value, then you already have it? Since I'm not seeing the full picture here, its a little hard to see why you can't do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

this does the trick for me `wire:click="sendString('{{ addslashes($search) }}', 'example')"`

`addslashes()`  automatically *escape* quote & double-quote so it can be safely transmitted.

so basically it change *didn't* to *didn\'t*

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it